# aptana has no code assist for very simple functionality?

Tags: aptana

using aptana studio 3, I found the following has no code assist

```
var myDate=new Date();
mtDate.
```

Anything wrong with it?

Comment: Is that the *only* piece of code that doesn't have code assistance? Or is it broken for *all* of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug filed for JavaScript autocomplete in Aptana Studio 3:

https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272/tickets/1609-javascript-code-assist-does-not-work-in-aptana-3-preview-release

You can follow it to see the progress.

Answer (score 1):

One minor thing is that your variable is declared as "myDate", but you reference "mtDate". However, I confirmed that correcting the reference name only shows Object properties and not Date properties as well. A ticket was created for this item here:

https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272/tickets/2450-date-object-not-showing-correct-ca-in-js

And the good news is that has been resolved and will be available in the next nightly build.